# FrameBuffer construction crashing some Android devices?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, libgdx

So I'm constructing a FrameBuffer like this (I'm using LibGDX):

```
try
{
    _frameBuffer= new FrameBuffer(Format.RGBA4444, (int)getWidth(), (int)getHeight(), false);
}
catch (IllegalStateException e)
{
    _frameBuffer= new FrameBuffer(Format.RGBA8888, (int)getWidth(), (int)getHeight(), false);
}
```

(In case the device doesn't support RGBA4444 I fall back to RGBA8888).

This works great for almost everyone, but every day my Google Analytics crash reports show up with 2-4 crashes that occurs when constructing the FrameBuffer.  It's always the same device models, too:

- [Galaxy Tab 10.1 (Germany version?)](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_p7500_galaxy_tab_10_1_3g-3892.php)
- [G-Slate](http://www.gsmarena.com/t_mobile_g_slate-3932.php)
- [Iconia Tab A500](http://www.gsmarena.com/acer_iconia_tab_a500-3907.php)

---

Here is the error I'm receiving:

```
Thread: GLThread 17, Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: frame buffer couldn't be constructed: unknown error 0 at
com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.FrameBuffer.build(FrameBuffer.java:178) at
com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.FrameBuffer.<init>(FrameBuffer.java:97) at
...
```

I'm using LibGDX's FrameBuffer class. In this class, there are a number of possible errors that could be thrown. Note that I'm receiving the last one (the default one with no if-statement):

```
if (result == GL20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT)
    throw new IllegalStateException("frame buffer couldn't be constructed: incomplete attachment");
if (result == GL20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_DIMENSIONS)
    throw new IllegalStateException("frame buffer couldn't be constructed: incomplete dimensions");
if (result == GL20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_MISSING_ATTACHMENT)
    throw new IllegalStateException("frame buffer couldn't be constructed: missing attachment");
if (result == GL20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_UNSUPPORTED)
    throw new IllegalStateException("frame buffer couldn't be constructed: unsupported combination of formats");
throw new IllegalStateException("frame buffer couldn't be constructed: unknown error " + result);
```

I'm not sure what that means other than whatever this error is it doesn't fit into any of the other "categories."

Comment: Look at what OS version these devices are running and if it matches up with what the carriers distributed. Maybe these users are running custom ROMs that have an OpenGL bug. According to the API, result 0 is a generic error catch-all: http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glCheckFramebufferStatus.xml

Comment: It seems they're all running stock Android, versions 3.1, 3.2.1, and 4.0.4 - all seems to be within reason. I had an idea, could it be because the FBO dimensions are not power of 2? Would that cause this type of error on only a few devices? (I know I can just test it myself, but I won't have new analytics in over 24 hours.)

Comment: Don't know. Devices running 3.x are extremely rare, so that's kind of weird.

Comment: did you find a solution to this ?